# F# How to check if obj is generic type?

Tags: f#

This seems like it should be simple but is not - reflection is not behaving exactly as I expected.

```
type Key<'x> = Id of int | NoKey
type Address = {
    id: Key<Address>
    city : string
}
```

And a function that can take any obj. I want to check if that object type is of type Key - regardless of what the 'x is. Then if it is, I also want to know what the 'x is.

```
let Test (param: obj) =
    let paramType = param.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition()
    let addressType = typeof<Key<Address>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
    printfn $"{paramType}" (*Output:Project.Types+Key`1+Id[x]*)
    printfn $"{addressType}"(*Output: Proect.Types+Key`1[x]*)

let address {
        id=Id 6
        city="Indianapolis"
    }

Test address.id
```

Since the output for the `GetType` call seems to include the `Id` subtype, I'm not sure how I match on that - because I don't care if it's an Id or NoKey. I just care if the parent type is a Key of any generic type.

How do I test for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to get the generic type definition, you can use `typedefof` instead of `GetGenericTypeDefinition`:

```
let addressType = typedefof<Key<Address>>
```

Then, the key insight is that union constructors, though separate types from IL perspective, are not themselves generic. They *inherit* from the generic type `Key<'x>`, but themselves, generic they are not.

This is roughly how your `Key<'x>` definition would be compiled to C#:

```cs
class Key<x> {
  class Id : Key<x> { ... }

  class NoKey : Key<x> { ... }
}
```

Note that the `Id` and `NoKey` types don't have any angle brackets in them.

This insight yields an obvious conslusion: `param.GetType()` is `Id`, but to get to `Key<'x>` from it, you have to go `param.GetType().BaseType` - because `Id` is a subtype of `Key`, and `Key` is base type of `Id`.

From here, you can get the generic def via `GetGenericTypeDefinition`, and then compare it to `typedefof<Key<>>`:

```
let Test (param: obj) =
  let paramType = param.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
  let keyType = typedefof<Key<_>>
  paramType = keyType
```

P.S. Note that you probably want to protect against `BaseType` returning `null`, just in case `param` is actually an `obj`, which doesn't have a base type.